# How do I correctly build GCC on an ARM based device

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, arm

I got my self an ARM based development board (NVIDIA Jetson K1).

The thing is already equipped with Ubuntu system. I was able to use gcc 4.8 directly on the device, but it doesn't contain g++. Installing g++ with apt-get as usual wouldn't work because nobody ever bothered to maintain a complete ppa supporting ARM architecture.

Now I tried to compile the latest GCC manually. Everything went smooth when I compile and installed the requirements (MPC, MPFR, GMP). But I failed building GCC itself, and found out that the mad error in `config.log` telling me that a working C++ compiler can not be found.

I believe there must be a way to get a working g++ compiler working on the device itself rather than having to cross compile. Does anyone have a clue on how this can be done?

Comment: Supposedly you should be able to find a binary suited for ARM and download GCC as a binary--I may be wrong, but this reminds me of what I did once to port C code to Android.

Comment: Debian/Ubuntu is especially popular so this shouldn't be too hard to find, from what I can gather.

Comment: @Cinch Ubuntu is popular, but ARM support is very poor. Almost nothing is ready as binary. I can't even get a working `curl`.

Comment: Perhaps you could run a ARM virtual machine, compile g++ and gcc, and transfer the binaries to your machine via Internet or flash drive?

Comment: ARM has been well supported by Ubuntu for, what, 5-6 years now. I don't know what is wrong with your setup, but it isn't that.

Comment: @unixsmurf Well, after several hours of struggling. I did find out how to get software support for ARM. Thank you for keeping me on the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The message is right. GCC 4.8 is [written in C++](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/266235/isnt-there-a-chicken-and-egg-issue-since-gcc-is-written-in-c-itself) so it needs to be compiled with a C++ (cross) compiler.